# How to Convert A String to Object In Kotlin

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jackson

I have a string as following:

```
IngestDataRequestDto(initiatorEmail=sample@sample.com, ingestionDetails=IngestionDetails(selectedColumns={...
```

I want to convert this to IngestDataRequestDto.kt data class.

I tried to use deserilize with jackson and also direct casting but both not worked

```
  try {
      previousValue = SerializationService.deserialize(sample.previousValue, IngestDataRequestDto::class)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      previousValue = sample.previousValue as IngestDataRequestDto
    }
```

try gives jackson error, catch string to object exception

Comment: can you give more details about error ?

Answer (score 1):

That string seems to have been generated by a `toString()` call on some `IngestDataRequestDto` object, so it is not properly formatted as a Json or anything like that and, as such, can't be deserialized using these steps.

For this task, you'll need to make your own implementation of a deserializer, maybe using regex or, if that string always follows that format, you can make a template to extract the information you need.

Even though, this is definitely not the best way to do this and you should search for what generated that string in the first place and check if there's a better way to get that object's data.